# Which is the suitable Openssl version for m68k processor

Tags: linux, openssl, coldfire

Whic openssl version (source code tar ball) is suitable for m68k cross compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded OpenSsl 0.9.8 and was able to cross compile it for M68K cold fire processor.